# Two JQuery API's in ASP.Net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have two API's of JQuery in ASP.Net,

[This is for the message box](http://akquinet.github.com/jquery-toastmessage-plugin/)

[And this is for the progress bar](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Progressbar#option-value)

What should  I do to avoid conflict between the two of them? because if I declare the **source** of API so the progress bar will work, then the message box will not work.

this is the source for **message box**

```
 <script src="<%# Page.ResolveUrl("~/Style/javascript/jquery-1.7.1.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="<%# Page.ResolveUrl("~/Style/javascript/jquery.toastmessage.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And this is the source for **Progress Bar**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: What happens if you include `jQuery-1.7.1.js` and `jquery-ui.min.js` and `jquery.toastmessage.js` but _not_ `jQuery-1.5/jquery.min.js`?

Comment: @nnnnnn - If I include that, the messagebox will work...

Comment: It seems like you should update your progress bar usage to suppot jQuery 1.7